# Windows Phone Listbox Selection to Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, windows-phone

**Question:**

What is the simpliest way for pre-defined items in a Listbox to be populated to a TextBox (Preferably single selection) In a Windows 7 Phone Enviroment?

***Example:*** I select "*Bob*" from the list box and then "*Bob*" is then displayed in the text box instantly so the user doesn't need to type in a Username, and can instead use a pre-made username from the list of Usernames.

**Problems:**

- I've tried looking for these little things and found no solutions.
- The solutions I did find are incredibly vague.
- Many videos on YouTube and elsewhere haven't really covered this for Windows 7
- I fear Windows 8 is different.
- Right now, my code fails to populate the Textbox with the Listbox Selection.

**Current Code:**

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,175,0,488" Name="textBox1" 
Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedValue}" Width="298" FontSize="20"
BorderBrush="Transparent" OpacityMask="#6E030303" Foreground="#FFEBC285" Background="Black"
FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" MaxLength="7">
```

Comment: Is this MVVM approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML you can do something like this

```
<ListBox name="lb"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

What this does is it databinds the `TextBox.Text` property to the `ListBox.SelectedValue` property`. The Textbox should populate when you select new items in the listbox.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this! I put this on the backburner so sorry for not responding sooner.

Comment: @user3486320 please remember that if it works to come back and upvote and checkmark this as the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I used this but nothing changed. I don't know what's up. When I make selections from my listbox nothing is populating.

Comment: So one thing you will notice about stack overflow is that it follows a pattern.  "Your Question, Your Code, The Problem, The Exception" If you follow this pattern youll get answers more often

Comment: I understand that, I am saying there is a pattern. Follow the pattern as much as you can.